# Como ver o valor de um define ou macro no gdb?

Tags: c, debug, gdb, macro

Tenho a seguinte linha de código:

```
int a = MAX(b,c);
```

Como verificar a definição da macro `MAX(b,c)`? As vezes, uma mesma macro é definida de vários jeitos diferentes num código (por exemplo, dependendo da arquitetura). Isso ajudaria nestes casos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro, compile o programa com a flag `-g3`, para pedir ao gcc que inclua todos níveis de informação de depuração, incluindo expansões de macro.

No gdb, utilize o comando `macro expand` para expandir a macro. Por exemplo,

```
#define MAX(x, y) (((x) > (y)) ? (x) : (y))
```

No gdb:

```
(gdb) expand macro MAX(a,b)
>> (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

Para ver o valor de um define, utilize o comando `info macro MACRO`.